# Managing Android ORMLite Concurrency and Overwriting

Tags: android, database, concurrency, android-asynctask, ormlite

I'm trying to solve a (hypothetical) concurrency problem in my Android app that uses ORMLite for the database management.
In particular, I have a `ContentService` class that manages the database, here's some code (simplified to understand the problem):

```
public ContentManagerImpl(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    configure();
    // Once configured, get the DatabaseHelper
    DatabaseManager.configure(context);
}

private void configure() {
    // If needed, unzip a folder with an sqlite file 
    // representing the database and saves it on device 
}

@Override
public void checkForUpdate() {
    // Checks if new database version is available
    new CheckForUpdateTask(CheckForUpdateTask.CheckForUpdateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckForUpdateFinished(boolean updateNeeded) {
            if (updateNeeded) {
                update();
            }
        }
    }).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}

@Override
public void update() {
    // Downloads the new database zip, unzip the folder and sava an sqlite file 
    // representing the database 
    new UpdateTask(mContext, mMetaData, new UpdateTask.UpdateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdateFinished() {
            DatabaseManager.refresh();
        }
    }).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
```

This class is created in the onCreate method of my Android `Application` class.

Since in the app I have only one `Activity`, the `checkForUpdate` method is called every time the `onResume` of that activity is called.

The problem is, sometimes when there's an update needed and the app is resumed (or even when first launched) I get an exception on a database query performed inside the `DatabaseManager.configure()` and `DatabaseManager.refresh()` methods.

That's because I try to get the first element of a single-row table but the query returns an empty list. It seems that the database is not ready, or that someone is still writing on it. I've also tried some lock mechanism but without luck.

So, since is the main (UI) thread that overwrites the database file, my questions are:

- Can it be a problem to access the database from multiple threads/tasks?
- Can I perform database queries on a separated thread if I write the db file on the UI thread?

Thank you all for your support.